# Open pegasus association provider

Tags: c++, wbem

I am developing a SMI-S provider using openpegasus,

when I try

```
cimserver "cimcli -n root/ift a CIM_StoragePool -i"
```

console shows instance list of CIM_StoragePool,

which means that `enumerateInstanceNames` method in Instance provider works,

but, when I select a instance,there is nothing happening.

My associator method in association provider did not be called.

I register association provider in my mof below:

```
  instance of PG_ProviderModule 
  {
     Name = "IFTComputerSystemModule";
     Location = "IFT_ComputerSystemProvider";
     Vendor = "Infortrend";
     Version = "2.4.0";
     InterfaceType = "C++Default";
     InterfaceVersion = "2.1.0";
  };

  instance of PG_Provider 
  {
     ProviderModuleName = "IFTComputerSystemModule";
     Name = "IFT_ComputerSystemProvider";
  };

  instance of PG_ProviderCapabilities 
  {
     ProviderModuleName = "IFTComputerSystemModule";
     ProviderName = "IFT_ComputerSystemProvider";
     CapabilityID = "1";
     ClassName = "CIM_ComputerSystem";
     Namespaces = {"root/ift"};
     ProviderType = { 2, 3 }; // Instance
     SupportedProperties = NULL; // All properties
     SupportedMethods = NULL; // All methods
  };
```

Is there anyone could help ? thanks a lot!

Comment: ps: I try "cimcli -n root/ift a CIM_ComputerSystem" also have the same result, and I have also registered the association class which related to CIM_ComputerSystem.

Comment: part of trace of cimserver  as below:
" Calling provider.associators: CIMServerControlProvider:InteropProvider"

but CIMServerControlProvider:InteropProvider is not the module and provider i implement, seems that cimserver call to wrong provider.

i like to know how to fix it, thanks.